# jQuery traversing order - depth first

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a bunch of nested checkboxes. I would like to make a selection of all checkboxes and have the 'deepest' elements first in that collection. Consider the following html:

```
<div id="selection"></div>
<div>
    <label>A: <input id="a" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
    <div>
        <label>B: <input id="b" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
        <label>C: <input id="c" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
    </div>
    <label>D: <input id="d" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
    <label>E: <input id="e" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
    <div>
        <label>F: <input id="f" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
        <label>G: <input id="g" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
        <div>
            <label>H: <input id="h" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
            <label>I: <input id="i" type="checkbox" /></label><br/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <label>J: <input id="j" type="checkbox" /></label><br/>
</div>
```

I'm using some jQuery to print the selection order:

```
var x = '';

$('input').each(function(){
    x += $(this).attr('id') + ' - ';
});

$('#selection').text(x.substr(0, x.length - 3));
```

The result is: `a - b - c - d - e - f - g - h - i - j`.
I would like the order or the selected elements to be **`I, H, G, F, C, B, J, E, D, A`** or **`H, I, B, C, F, G, A, D, E, J`**. How can I reorder the selection to be compatible with what I want? Or is their a way to make the initial selection the way I want?

Ow... and for all you fiddlers out there: http://jsfiddle.net/hze3M/4/! Go nuts! :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var x = '';
var ar = [];
$('input').each(function(){
    ar.push({length: $(this).parents().length, elmt: $(this)});
});

ar.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a.length - b.length > 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (a.length - b.length < 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
});

for (var i=0; i<ar.length; i++) {
    x += (ar[i].elmt.attr("id")) + ' - ';
};    

$('#selection').text(x);
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hze3M/7/

EDIT:

here another solution:

```
$.fn.sortByDepth = function() {
    var ar = this.map(function() {
            return {length: $(this).parents().length, elt: this}
        }).get(),
        result = [],
        i = ar.length;


    ar.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.length - b.length;
    });

    while (i--) {
        result.push(ar[i].elt);
    }
    return $(result);
};


var x = $('input').sortByDepth().map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(' - ');

$('#selection').text(x);
```

Credits here : [Create a jQuery object collection from separate jQuery objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5757150/create-a-jquery-object-collection-from-seperate-jquery-objects/5757230#5757230)

Comment: Cool! I'm looking of a way to incorporate or extend this in jQuery. I would like something like `$('input').sortByDept().each(`.

Comment: look at my edit, you have another implementation of what you are looking for

Comment: Waaaah! Nice!! Very nice indeed!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = new Array();
    $('input').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        a.push({id:$this.attr('id'),level:$this.parents('div').length});
    });
    a.sort(sortByLevel);
    /*for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++){
        console.log('id: '+a[i].id+'; level:'+a[i].level);
    }*/
});

function sortByLevel(a,b){
    return b.level - a.level;
}
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sorted = $('input').sortByDepth();
    sorted.each(function(){
        console.log($(this).attr('id') );
    });
});

(function( $ ){
    $.fn.sortByDepth = function() {
        return $(this).sort(function(a,b){
            return $(b).parents('div').length - $(a).parents('div').length;
        });
    };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: although it seems pointless since alexl beat me to the punch. but i took the time to write this, so i'm posting it anyway. :)

Comment: Hahaha... it happens sometimes. His answers uses parents() (without div), but I like your sorter more.

Comment: Any way of extending jquery with your code to get something like? I would like to be able to do `$('input').orderInDepth().each(`. Any ideas?

Comment: what would 'orderInDepth()' return?  all those checkboxes that are at the same level?

Comment: Based on a selection, like $('input'), it will sort the array. It will actually do your sort by level :-).

Comment: Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @ChristThompson but the performance of your first code was beter, because you first calculated the depth. In the new code you are calculating the depth on each bubble of the bubble sort.

Comment: Ow... I see what you are doing... I would not return ID's but the entire collection ;-)

Comment: this is just returning a sorted jquery collection.  you can modify it to return an array of objects as i was doing before. but it sounds like this is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional jQuery-heavy variation on @alexi's answer (same basic idea):

```
var $sorted = $('input:checkbox').sort(function(cb1, cb2) {
  return $(cb2).parents().length - $(cb1).parents().length();
});
```

That would give you a jQuery object with the checkboxes arranged in the order you want.  Note that the depth comparison is done "backwards" because you want the deepest ones first. The JavaScript sort *appears* to be stable, as far as I can tell, so when depth is equal the pre-existing DOM ordering will naturally be retained.

*edit* — probably obvious, but if you wanted to see the list of "id" values you'd just do:

```
var idList = $sorted.map(function() { return this.id }).get().join(' - ');
```

Comment: Maybe it would be a better idea to write a jQuery extension function that does the sorting. Like writing a `sortByDepth`.

Comment: @Kees that would certainly be a possibility, if it were something that a site needed to do often.

Answer (score 0):

Here shows the result: i - h - g - f - c - b - j - e - d - a

```
var x = '';
function getDepth(n) {
    var i = 0;
    while(n != document.body) {
        n = n.parentNode;
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
var list = $('input');

list.sort(function (a, b) {
    var a1 = getDepth(a), b1 = getDepth(b);
    if (a1 != b1)
        return b1 - a1;
    else
        return $(list).index(b) - $(list).index(a);
});
$(list).each(function(){
    x += $(this).attr('id') + ' - ';
});

$('#selection').text(x.substr(0, x.length - 3));
```

You can also try [this jsFiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/8m4HW/).

Comment: The other answers will outperform your answer, because their will be a lot of calculation. getDepth will be called a looooot of times.